# I need to reduce my box and image size for mobile devices using CSS and or bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to reduce the size of the box for mobile devices and cannot remember how to do so.
Currently, everything displays right on a website but on mobile it does not reflect and the box overfills the container

```
<div class="box"> 
        <img src="img/devban.png"  alt="logo"/>
        </div>





.cart-btn-m:hover {
        background-color: #64af3d;
    }

    .box {
        /* width: 100%; */
        width: 800px;
        height: 350px;
        border: 5px dashed #ffffff;
        align-self: center;
      }
      
      img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the width from the .box. The default of the width property is "auto", this means a block-level element, such as a div, will fill up the available space. I would change the width to max-width so the div can shrink (for mobile) but will not expand beyond 800px (for desktop). No need for the extra complexity of a media-query then.

Also you probably want to remove the height property on the img too. Height auto means it will preserve the aspect ratio.

```
.cart-btn-m:hover {
    background-color: #64af3d;
}

.box {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 5px dashed #ffffff;
    align-self: center;
}
  
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use media query for it

inside your styles

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .box {
    width: 400px;
  }
 .img {
     width: 80%; // change the values according to your requirement
 }
}
```

for more refer
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery

Comment: There are almost no mobile devices that have 400px (css pixels) available (that includes almost all iPhones, they have 375px available space). Best practice is to let the width default to auto.

Comment: Yea i was going to say the solution above didn't work any other recommendations?